# Dockerising and connecting between ws02 api manger and identity server as keymanager

Tags: docker, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I would like to dockerise api manager and identity server as keymanager and communicate between them. What are the steps to follow for this. How these should be made? Two separate docker images or using a docker compose and setting this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker compose resources are already available for API Manager and IS as KM in https://github.com/wso2/docker-apim/tree/master/docker-compose/apim-is-as-km-with-analytics. In this setup, APIM Analytics is also enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Compose file is the best way to do that. You can specify the ports that are exposed to each other and run all at once.

> Compose is a tool for defining and running multi-container Docker applications. With Compose, you use a Compose file to configure your application's services. Then, using a single command, you create and start all the services from your configuration.

The steps as mentioned in the reference below are:

1. Define your app's environment with a Dockerfile so it can be
   reproduced anywhere.
2. Define the services that make up your app in
   docker-compose.yml so they can be run together in an isolated
   environment.
3. Lastly, run docker-compose up and Compose will start and
   run your entire app.

Check here: https://github.com/docker/compose